# C++ "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector" error in a merge sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a c++ code which should use merge sort algorithm to sort a file containing 800,000+ words each on a new line.

**What I did ?**

To start off, I tried implementing the following merge sort algorithm and tried testing it on a small piece of input. I cannot figure out where I am getting index out of bounds error with the vector. If anyone could help me with this, I would really appreciate

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector<string> merge(const vector<string>& first,
                     const vector<string>& second) {
    // Write your code to merge vectors first and
    // second onto result.

    vector<string> output;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0 ;
    int size_first = sizeof(first);
    int size_second = sizeof(second);

    while(i < size_first || j < size_second){
        if (i < size_first && j < size_second){
            if (first.at(i) < second.at(j)){
                output.push_back(first.at(i));
                i++;
            }
            else{
                output.push_back(second.at(i));
                j++;
            }
        }
        else if (i < size_first){
            output.push_back(first.at(i));
            i++;
        }
        else{
            output.push_back(second.at(j));
            j++;
        }

    }
    return output;
}

void mergeSort(vector<string>& words) {
    if (words.size() <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    int n = words.size();
    int middle = n/2;

    vector<string> first_half(middle);
    for (int i = 0; i < middle; ++i) {
        first_half[i] = words[i];
    }

    vector<string> second_half(n - middle);
    for (int i = middle; i < n; ++i) {
        second_half[i - middle] = words[i];
    }

    words = merge(first_half, second_half);
}

void sort(vector<string>& words) {

    // Invoke mergeSort  here.
    mergeSort(words);
}

int main(){

    vector<string> names;
    names.push_back("Smith");
    names.push_back("Abinash");
    names.push_back("Ciara");
    names.push_back("Reeta");

    sort(names);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(first);` doesn't do what you think it does. Also your problem should be easy to fix using your debugger and stepping through your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `std::vector` has a `size()` member function that returns the number of  elements in vector. `sizeof(first)` returns size in bytes of [object representation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) of the type `std::vector<string>`, and that's not what you need.

   ```
    int size_first = sizeof(first);
    int size_second = sizeof(second);
   ```

   Should be replaced with

   ```
    int size_first = first.size();
    int size_second = second.size();
   ```
2. You have a typo in:

   ```
   else {
       output.push_back(second.at(i));
       j++;
   }
   ```

   Should be

   ```
       ...
       output.push_back(second.at(j))
   ```
3. And another one. You forgot about the main thing - calling `mergeSort` for the parts before calling `merge`. Should be:

   ```
   mergeSort(first_half);
   mergeSort(second_half);
   words = merge(first_half, second_half);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

you are determining the size of the vector wrong:

```
int size_first = sizeof(first);
int size_second = sizeof(second);
```

replace it by

```
size_t size_first = first.size();
size_t size_second = second.size();
```